# ntpd uses wrong server

Tags: debian, ntpd

I recently moved my main time-server to another system, e.g. `old.fqdn` to `new.fqdn`. All subordinate ntpd daemons use `ntp.fqdn` as server, which is a CNAME now pointing to `new.fqdn`, i.e. `host ntp.fqdn` on that system yields:

```
ntp.fqdn is an alias for new.fqdn.
new.fqdn has address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

However `ntpq -p` yields:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
    old.fqdn     .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

which is consistent, since `old.fqdn` has been shut down. But why does it stick to that server? This is `/etc/ntp.conf`:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable
server ntp.fqdn iburst
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
```

And of course `ntpd` has been restarted after the DNS change. Also `ntpdate -s ntp.fqdn` is able to synchronize, and other systems on the network using the exact same configuration work perfectly. The only apparent difference is that those systems never used `old.fqdn` before. Is there any other place, where `ntpd` keeps record of its parental server?

System is current Debian Jessie: ntp 1:4.2.6.p5+dfsg-7+deb8u2, amd64

**Update:** I began to re-install ntp (`apt-get --purge remove ntp && apt-get install ntp`) on the workstations. After re-installation the same configuration works as expected.

**Solution:** The reason is that ntpd is not started with `/etc/ntp.conf`, but with `/var/lib/ntp/ntp.conf.dhcp`. The latter had the IP of `old.fqdn` hardcoded. Yes, in the past the systems have been configured by DHCP, currently they aren't.

The Debian start script `/etc/init.d/ntp` checks whether the file exists, and uses it for configuration instead. So the solution to the problem is to delete `/var/lib/ntp/ntp.conf.dhcp`. Don't know why I didn't check `ps aux` earlier.

Comment: I think you forget to change reverse DNS zone (PTR records).

Comment: There was nothing to change. old.fqdn has an IP distinct from new.fqdn. The reverse PTR are fine for both. ntp.fqdn as a CNAME has no reverse entry.

Comment: Is showed `ntpd.conf` from ntp.fqdn server?

Comment: No these are the workstations. ntp.fqdn aka new.fqdn isn't that much different, but of course has external server entries..

Comment: OK. Then check PTR record by command `host ip-address-of-ntp.fqdn` on workstation.

Comment: root@foo:~# host ntp.fqdn
ntp.fqdn is an alias for new.fqdn.
new.fqdn has address 172.16.xxx.xxx
root@foo:~# host 172.16.xxx.xxx
xxx.xxx.16.172.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer new.fqdn.

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the question. If one of the given answers  holds the solution, accept it, otherwise post your solution as an answer. It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own questions and accept those answers.

Answer (score 1):

NTP doesn't automatically retry DNS lookups when using the `server` directive.  Switch `server` to `pool` and restart NTP to get this behaviour.

Comment: Did that, restarted ntpd, but it still sticks to old.fqdn.

Comment: Seems from the edits above like the restart didn't work, and the reinstall had the effect of restarting.  Check syslog for messages from ntpd and you'll probably find that it didn't restart when you thought it did.

Comment: At least the ports were deallocated. Otherwise ntpdate had not worked. Syslog has start and stop messages from ntpd with different PID.

Comment: Well, glad you got it fixed, but seems we're none the wiser about the real cause... :-)

Comment: Didn't fix it apart from re-installation. Saved one system for further investigation to learn something about ntpd.

Answer (score 1):

I think, `ntpd` return the first PTR record as server name and it is `old.fqdn`. If you'll delete this record you'll get the second PTR record `new.fqdn` for same ip address of the time server. Ntpd works with ip addresses, it resolves domain names to ip at start.

You can see this ip address by command on workstation:

```
ntpq -p -n localhost
```

Comment: old.fqdn and new.fqdn have different IP addresses. I don't have multiple A records for ntp.fqdn. ntp.fqdn is a CNAME, i.e. ntp.fqdn has no reverse at all and new.fqdn doesn't share anything with old.fqdn.

Comment: Do you see ip address of `old.fqdn` by command on workstation:
`ntpq -p -n localhost`?

Comment: Yes, this at least is consistent.

Comment: Then you need to check ntpd logs.

Comment: There's nothing spectacular in the logs: protocol precision, interfaces to listen to, "peers refreshed", and "listening on routing socket ...". No notion where the old IP comes from. And there doesn't seem to be any config option to make logging more verbose.

Comment: Did you see in the logs that NTPD read its configuration from `/etc/ntp.conf` file? Does command `host ntpd.fqdn` (on workstation) return new ip address of new NTP server?

Comment: The logs don't show, which configuration is read, but ps did - and that was the solution to this riddle ... Thanks!